# How to position the LeftNav to not cover the AppBar

Tags: material-ui

Before [this](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/pull/2678) PR I could easily move my LeftNav down to not cover the AppBar by applying a 'top' attribute to the components style.
Now that this PR applies the style to the root element this no longer works and the LeftNav is full-height.
Is there a way to style the root element to get the LeftNav down again ?
(applying the top-style to the root element does not work because the inner LeftNav has inline styles of 'position: fixed and top: 0')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<LeftNav containerStyle={ {'top': '75px'} }>`

Comment: This breaks when you scroll to the bottom of the page. The LeftNav ends up have a `75px` gap between it and the top of the screen.